# How does 'client_min_messages' setting affect an application using libpq?

Tags: postgresql, libpq

From [postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES),

> client_min_messages (enum)
>
> Controls which message levels are sent to the client. Valid values are DEBUG5, DEBUG4, DEBUG3, DEBUG2, DEBUG1, LOG, NOTICE, WARNING, ERROR, FATAL, and PANIC. Each level includes all the levels that follow it. The later the level, the fewer messages are sent. The default is NOTICE. Note that LOG has a different rank here than in log_min_messages.

I am assuming that these `messages` are not the same as the `results` (`PQResult`) of the commands executed. If so, how do I read these messages through libpq? Would there be an impact of these `messages` on the application`s performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages are sent as a different message type on the PostgreSQL protocol, usually interleaved with the result stream. `libpq` sees them and picks them out, then adds them to a queue of notifications you can examine.

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-notice-processing.html).

Comment: So, if one were to never process these 'notifications', can these be disabled? The application I'm currently building just executes some SQL statements and then checks for the error in the returned `PQResult`.

Comment: @svr That's why there is a `client_min_messages` setting. Set it yo `error` and you won't get notices, only errors that result in query stop and transaction abort.